# How to get corresponding FIELD to MAX(DATE) in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

My two tables are as follows :

```
Table 1 : Transaction
TRANS_ID (primary key), TRANS_DATE, TRANS_STATUS, USER_ID (Foreign_Key)
```

The same user_id will be repeated when status change

```
Table 2 : Users
USER_ID (Primary_Key), USER_NAME, USER_DOB, OTHER_INFO
```

I want to get the user information along with last transaction status.

I am familiar with the following query.

```
SELECT MAX(Transaction.TRANS_DATE),Transaction.TRANS_STATUS, Users.USER_NAME, Users.USER_DOB
FROM Users
INNER_JOIN Transaction ON Transaction.USER_ID = Users.USER_ID 
WHERE Transaction.USER_ID = @UserID
```

I pass the `UserID` with `Parameter.AddWithValue`. Unfortunately, this method does not return the `TRANS_STATUS` for the `MAX(TRANS_DATE)`. It does return `MAX(TRANS_DATE)` but `TRANS_STATUS` is the first occurrence, not the corresponding `STATUS` to `MAX(TRANS_DATE)` record.

Please let me know how I could get the `TRANS_STATUS` for the `MAX(TRANS_DATE)`. I prefer using `INNER JOIN` but recommendations are appreciated.

I could not still get to working.

Here are my table scripts.

```
CREATE TABLE `Transactions` (
  `TRANS_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TRANS_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `TRANS_STATUS` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRANS_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TRANS_ID_UNIQUE` (`TRANS_ID`),
  KEY `USER_ID_idx` (`USER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `Users` (`USER_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `USER_DOB` datetime NOT NULL,
  `OTHER_INFO` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `USER_ID_UNIQUE` (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join on the subquery for max TRANS_DATE

```
    select t.max_trans, t.USER_NAME, t.USER_DOB
    from Transaction 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(Transaction.TRANS_DATE) max_trans, 
             Transaction.USER_ID, Users.USER_NAME, Users.USER_DOB
        FROM Users
        INNER_JOIN Transaction ON Transaction.USER_ID = Users.USER_ID 
        WHERE Transaction.USER_ID = @UserID
    ) t on Transaction.USER_ID = t.USER_ID and t.max_trans = Transaction.TRANS_DATE
```

Comment: Looks like there is a syntax error near 'select SELECT' ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right this could work for you

```
SELECT A.USER_ID AS USER_ID, A.TRANS_DATE AS TRANS_DATE, TRANS_STATUS, USER_NAME, USER_DOB
FROM
(SELECT USER_ID, MAX(TRANS_DATE) AS TRANS_DATE FROM TRANSACTION
GROUP BY USER_ID) A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT USER_ID, TRANS_DATE, TRANS_STATUS FROM TRANSACTION) B
ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
AND A.TRANS_DATE=B.TRANS_DATE
INNER JOIN USERS U
ON A.USER_ID=U.USER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Users.USER_NAME, Users.USER_DOB
FROM Users usr INNER JOIN(
    SELECT Transaction.TRANS_STATUS, MAX(Transaction.TRANS_DATE)
    FROM Transaction GROUP BY Transaction.TRANS_STATUS) trs ON trs.USER_ID=usr.USER_ID
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I tested this and I get the error : "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Users.USER_NAME' in 'field list'".

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAST_VALUE function

```
SELECT Top 1 
      u.User_ID
     ,u.user_name
     ,u.user_dob
     ,u.other_info
    ,LAST_VALUE(t.Trans_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_id ORDER BY 
              t.Trans_Date RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Max_Tran_Date
    ,LAST_VALUE(t.trans_status) OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_id ORDER BY 
              t.Trans_Date RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Last_Status
FROM #Users as u
INNER JOIN #Transaction as t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.User_ID = @UserID
```

Comment: I have not tested this but looks very complex. How is the efficiency of this ?